# Bootstrap card component

Tags: html, css, layout, bootstrap

I am using [Bootstrap v5.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/) to create a card layout, and I want it to be SEO-friendly (see [this link](https://www.reliablesoft.net/seo-friendly-design/) for my SEO-friendly criteria).

Below is my card component I wish to optimize and, if possible, to drop some classes from `<div>` elements for cleaner markup.

I am considering to put all styling inside a style file, which is represented here as style tag. If I will go for that option, then how do I organize these styles?

What are other *objective* flaws in my markup as you can tell?

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
.card-custom {
  width: 400px;
}
</style>
<div class="card-custom rounded-2 shadow-sm d-flex flex-column">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wNabyl4.jpg" class="card-img-top rounded-0" alt="Hello World" />

    <div class="px-3 py-3 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between gap-4 flex-grow-1">
            <div>
                Subheader Line
            </div>

        <div class="text-break flex-grow-1">
            <h3 class="fw-bold fs-4">Card Title</h3>

            Content Content Content of Dynamic Length
        </div>

            <div>
                Footer of Static Length
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: I am going to wait 24 hours to down vote and vote to delete in case improvements are made. I suggest you read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) because our rules are different. We want to see more code so we can do a better review.

Comment: Thank you all for tips, I'll clarify my question with more code and better structure.

Comment: What does your bootstrap card component do?  It's a layout.  What kind of layout?  Flexible?  Fixed columns?  Something else?  What are you hoping will be the result of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### *I wish to optimize and, if possible, to drop some classes from `<div>` elements for cleaner markup*

I see one places where two classes can be combined: `px-3 py-3` on the `<div>` under the `<div>` containing text `Subheader Line` can be simplified to `p-3`.

Other than that one possible change might be to use a bootstrap style class name that semantically describes what styles the class contains. If the only style rule in `.custom-card` is `width: 400px` then the name could be changed to something like `w-400px`. If there was a desire to make the width relative to the parent element or the viewport then [one of the bootstrap `w-*` classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/) could be used instead.

Note: I added class `m-2` to the outer `<div>` in the sample below to add a slight margin around the card but that is not required. I also used the <kbd>Tidy</kbd> button to make the indentation consistent

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
  .w-400px {
    width: 400px;
  }
</style>
<div class="w-400px rounded-2 shadow-sm d-flex flex-column m-2">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wNabyl4.jpg" class="card-img-top rounded-0" alt="Hello World" />

  <div class="p-3 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between gap-4 flex-grow-1">
    <div>
      Subheader Line
    </div>

    <div class="text-break flex-grow-1">
      <h3 class="fw-bold fs-4">Card Title</h3>

      Content Content Content of Dynamic Length
    </div>

    <div>
      Footer of Static Length
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```